# How to delete a line break in an external file?

Tags: python

In a text file I'm trying to replace, I'm trying to delete an extra line break ie. convert

```
test="
123"
```

to

```
test="123"
```

What I currently have is:

```
f = open("file.txt")
o = open("newfile.txt","w")
while 1:
  line = f.readline()
  if not line: break
  line = line.replace('test="\r','test="')
  o.write(line)
o.close()
```

The problem is that it returns

```
  test="123"
```

with an **invisible character** between the <"> and the <123>. Is there some better alternative to what I'm currently doing? I'm not very proficient with python; thanks!

Comment: Is the external file only 2 lines long?

Comment: what invisible character? `\n`?

Comment: @mgilson, no it's extremely long with multiple instances of said 'test'. The script also includes many other lines, but they work, so it isn't a problem.

Comment: @MarcB I copied and pasted it and it's technically a Line Feed symbol.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code have some flaws:

- f is not closed at the end
- you only replace `\r`, ignoring the `\n` on windows - this is your "invisible" character I think (windows uses `\r\n` as a linebreak in textfiles, linux `\n` and Mac `\r`)

here is another version (might be close to that what you want;) ):

```
with file("file.txt", "r") as f:
    with file("newfile.txt", "w") as o:
        o.write("".join(s.replace("\r", "").replace("\n","") 
                for s in f.readlines()))
```

Comment: Oh thanks! This works. I tried using \r, \r\r, \n, \n\n, but not \r\n. That seemed to have fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this (in my opinion) is to enable [Universal Newline Support](http://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-universal-newlines).  This will then make your code work with files made on any operating system (Windows, Mac or Linux).

To do this you add the 'U' specification when reading and writing your files.  In your example:

```
with open("file.txt", "rU") as f:
    with open("newfile.txt","w") as o: 
        for line in f.readlines():
            o.write(line.replace("\n", ""))
```

This requires that Python was built with Universal Newline Support, which is the default.

Comment: I get an error for your second line:
clean-xml2.py:4: ValueError: universal newline mode can only be used with modes starting with 'r'

Comment: Oops, thanks for catching that. Should have been `with open("newfile.txt", "w") as o:`.